# Error when running wsdl tool on Sabre GetReservation file

Tags: wsdl, sabre

I am running wsdl.exe tool on  http://files.developer.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/pnrservices/GetReservation_1.19.0.wsdl, following the [Sabre .NET sample](https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/SACS-DotNet), and the [Get Itinerary Resources](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/get_itinerary/resources) which warn that: "TravelItineraryReadRQ API will be decommissioned; please use GetReservationRQ"

But failed with error:
**WSDL: error WSDL1: There was an error processing 'http://files.developer.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/pnrservices/GetReservation_1.19.0.wsdl'.
The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
- The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
- There was an error downloading 'http://files.developer.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/pnrservices/PNRBuilderTypes_v1.19.0.xsd'.
- The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.**

Answer (score 1):

.Net has some issues with choice elements and the way Sabre created some WSDLs. You can find more information at https://developer.sabre.com/resources/api_versioning.

Comment: I don't think that this issue is due to the choice element conflicts. As you can see this link http://files.developer.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/pnrservices/PNRBuilderTypes_v1.19.0.xsd is broken. I think that this caused the error. Thanks

Comment: Sabre developers fixed the WSDL file now.

Comment: Thank you PianoLontano23

Answer (score 1):

Sabre team fixed the broken address and now there is no error when running the wsdl tool. Thanks